# Should I use contractions on a non-fiction work?

Tags: style, non-fiction

> It is many things, as we’ll see in Chapter TBD, but at its heart, it is just software.

I heard it was bad to use contractions, but it seems a bit wordy to say: *as we will see*.

Comment: Shamoon, Does the question John linked to answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're exactly right, as using "we will" might seem excessively formal even for non-fiction, but you've avoided "it's" which, apart from the informality, increases the chance that somewhere one instance will lose it's comma, or one will sneak into the possessive as in the example a few words ago.